# Changing output text colour when positive / negative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple bit of jQuery below which is working as expected. I would however like to change it so if the number is positive it turns green and if it is negative it turns red. I know the CSS part and so the styling isn't an issue. I am just unsure how to add the class depending on the result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#cost_price").on("keyup",function() {
        var totalcost= $("#_regular_price").val() - $(this).val() 
        $(".total_cost").html(totalcost);
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
var $totalCost = $(".total_cost");

if(totalCost < 0) {
   $totalCost.removeClass("green").addClass("red");
} else {
   $totalCost.removeClass("red").addClass("green");
}

$totalCost.html(totalCost);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This didn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ejHrc/58/ rather than $(this) shouldn't it be $(total_cost)

Comment: @user2595441 You have a bunch of errors in your JavaScript and your CSS. The attribute is `color` and not `colour`. You're missing the `#` sign for one of the color codes, and the classes need to start with `.`. Otherwise you're targetting elements called `red` and `green`, which don't exist. You're also using `totalCost` in the `.html()` call, but your variable is called `totalcost`. Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxywL/).

Comment: Sorry for that. I have checked your updated fiddle but that seems to add both the green and red class and the text is only turning green even if it is a negative number?

Comment: @user2595441 No problem. It appears there was a bug in my code. You need to remove the old class before adding the new one. I've updated my code. [Check out the fiddle now](http://jsfiddle.net/MxywL/1/).

Comment: That is perfect!! Thank you very much for your help! and sorry for my rushing! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary statement:

```
totalcost < 0 ? $(".total_cost").addClass("negative") : $(".total_cost").addClass("positive")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a .negative class that sets it to red then Javascript applies it or not

```
$("#cost_price").on("keyup",function(){
  var totalcost= $("#_regular_price").val() - $(this).val() 
  $(".total_cost").html(totalcost);
  if(totalcost < 0) $(this).addClass("negative");
  else $(this).removeClass("negative");
});
```

Comment: this appars to be adding the negative class to mytextfield not total_cost. http://jsfiddle.net/ejHrc/59/

Comment: Add and remove the class to Whatever you want to change http://jsfiddle.net/ejHrc/59/ IMHO, the class should be applied to the text which is being modified (in this case, #mytextfield)

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
$(".total_cost").html(totalcost).addClass(Math.abs(totalCost) === totalCost ? 'positive' : 'negative');
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KrWqy/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(totalcost >= 0){
    if($(".total_cost").hasClass('red')
        $(".total_cost").removeClass('red');
    if(!$(".total_cost").hasClass('green')
        $(".total_cost").addClass('green');
}
else{
    if($(".total_cost").hasClass('green')
        $(".total_cost").removeClass('green');
    if(!$(".total_cost").hasClass('red')
        $(".total_cost").addClass('red');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is to use css3's attrib matching, and a tiny bit of js to publish the *value* property to a real *attribute*:

```
 <style> input[alt^='-'] { color: red; } </style>
 <input oninput="this.alt=this.value"  />
```

which shows red if the value starts with "-". you can use a type=number and min/max attribs to further improve the user interface.

tested in chrome, ff, and IE9. use onkeyup for IE8 compat.